# Regex problem: IsMatch method never returns

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex issue that I need help with. Its trying to validate an Email address.

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z0-9]([_\.\-]?[A-Za-z0-9]+)*\@[A-Za-z0-9]([_\.\-]?[A-Za-z0-9]+)*\.[A-Za-z0-9]([_\.\-]?[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$|^$");
rx.IsMatch("john.gilbert.stu.seattle.washington.us");
```

The **IsMatch** method never returns for that particular string. It goes into some infinite loop. Can anybody see what the problem is with the pattern.

Thanks!

Comment: not sure what the error is. I always construct regexes using an online regex tester like http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm
I think that's a really fast TDD approach for creating regexes. (PS There are many more of these, just google)

Comment: It does return, just very slowly.

Comment: I tried a few online regex testers and they return the "no match" result very quickly. Its just the C# Regex that returns after a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first "+" is the problem, if you remove it it runs

Comment: Actually, the plus signs are fine--in fact, you need more of them.  It's the question marks that don't belong. `^[A-Za-z0-9]+([_.-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+([_.-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$`

Answer (score 1):

(some stuff)* is bad. See here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you the following to validate an email address:

```
try
{
    MailAddress addr = new MailAddress("foo@bar.com");
}
catch (FormatException exc)
{
    // The email address is not valid
}
```

Here's an [interesting read](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx).

Comment: I wish I could do this. Actually the regex is in an XSD file, which is used to validate big XML documents. To isolate my issue, I just took the part which had the problem, and wrote that quick test method above.

Comment: +1 for an interesting read, -1 for suggesting using exceptions in a non-exceptional circumstance.

Comment: @jloubert How do you know it's non-exceptional? If the circumstance was a method expected to send a mail to the address passed, then it's exceptional as there is no possible way to succeed at that point.

Comment: Good point -- if there was, say, a `Validate()` method and a `SendEmail()` method, this solution would be fine for `SendEmail()`; `Validate()` should have already caught any bad data, so an exception would be warranted. However, if the point of this question is to code the `Validate()` method itself, I would frown on this, because we can probably expect to get invalid data and handle it easily without resorting to an exception.