# Ignore existing spaces in converting CamelCase to string with spaces

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to split `camelCase` or `PascalCase` words to space separate collection of words.

So far, I have:

```
Regex.Replace(value, @"(\B[A-Z]+?(?=[A-Z][^A-Z])|\B[A-Z]+?(?=[^A-Z]))", " $0", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

It works fine for converting "TestWord" to "Test Word" and for leaving single words untouched, e.g. `Testing` remains `Testing`.

However, `ABCTest` gets converted to `A B C Test` when I would prefer `ABC Test`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
[A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z]+(?=[A-Z][a-z])|[a-z]+|[A-Z]+
```

[An example on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xM9xE2/3)

---

## How is it used in CS?

```
string strText = " TestWord asdfDasdf  ABCDef";
        
string[] matches = Regex.Matches(strText, @"[A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z]+(?=[A-Z][a-z])|[a-z]+|[A-Z]+")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Value)
                .ToArray();
            
string result = String.Join(" ", matches);
```

`result` = `'Test Word asdf Dasdf ABC Def'`

---

## How it works

In the example string:

```
TestWord qwerDasdf
ABCTest Testing    ((*&^%$CamelCase!"£$%^^))
asdfAasdf
AaBbbCD
```

`[A-Z][a-z]+` matches:

- [0-4]   `Test`
- [4-8]   `Word`
- [13-18] `Dasdf`
- [22-26] `Test`
- [27-34] `Testing`
- [45-50] `Camel`
- [50-54] `Case`
- [68-73] `Aasdf`
- [74-76] `Aa`
- [76-79] `Bbb`

`[A-Z]+(?=[A-Z][a-z])` matches:

- [19-22] `ABC`

`[a-z]+` matches:

- [9-13]   `qwer`
- [64-68]  `asdf`

`[A-Z]+` matches:

- [79-81]   `CD`

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it doesn't work when the value has a space already. It ends up doubling the space i.e. "ABC Test" becomes "ABC  Test" Equally " ABCTest" becomes " ABC Test" i.e. the leading space is kept.

Comment: @CiaranMartin I would use `Regex.match()` to get a `MatchCollection` of all the matches listed above. You can then cast this to an array and join it into a string using a single space separator. This keeps a lot of the logic out of your regex and makes the code more readable.

Comment: @CiaranMartin see my edit for the C# implementation.

Comment: If the input string contain numbers, or alphanumerics, they will be missing or corrupt in the final output.

Comment: Thanks @OhAuth It all makes sense now. I agree, getting the matches and then joining them is more straight forward instead of trying to handles spaces in the RegEx

Comment: @stribizhev OP only asks to "split camelCase or PascalCase words" so no need to worry about numbers. But your answer deserves +1 for a solid solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt:

```
(?<!^|\b|\p{Lu})\p{Lu}+(?=\p{Ll}|\b)|(?<!^\p{Lu}*|\b)\p{Lu}(?=\p{Ll}|(?<!\p{Lu}*)\b)
```

This regex can be used with `Regex.Replace` and  `$0` as a replacement string.

```
Regex.Replace(value, @"(?<!^|\b|\p{Lu})\p{Lu}+(?=\p{Ll}|\b)|(?<!^\p{Lu}*|\b)\p{Lu}(?=\p{Ll}|(?<!\p{Lu}*)\b)", " $0", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c!%5e%7c%5cb%7c%5cp%7bLu%7d)%5cp%7bLu%7d%2b(%3f%3d%5cp%7bLl%7d%7c%5cb)%7c(%3f%3c!%5e%5cp%7bLu%7d*%7c%5cb)%5cp%7bLu%7d(%3f%3d%5cp%7bLl%7d%7c(%3f%3c!%5cp%7bLu%7d*)%5cb)&i=ABC+Test%0d%0aTest+ABC%0d%0aTestWord%0d%0aTesting%0d%0aABCTest%0d%0acamlTst%0d%0acmlTdT%0d%0aTfTf%0d%0atTTT%0d%0aTestWord+asdfDasdf%0d%0aABCTest+Testing%0d%0aasdfAasdf%0d%0aAaBbbCD&r=+%240)

Regex Explanation:

- Contains 2 alternatives to account for a chain of capital letters before or after lowercase letters.
- `(?<!^|\b|\p{Lu})\p{Lu}+(?=\p{Ll}|\b)` - first alternative that matches several uppercase letters that are not preceded with a start of string, word boundary or another uppercase letter, and that are followed by a lowercase letter or a word boundary,
- `(?<!^\p{Lu}*|\b)\p{Lu}(?=\p{Ll}|(?<!\p{Lu}*)\b)` - the second alternative that matches a single capital letter that is not preceded with a start of string with optional uppercase letters right after, or word boundary and is followed by a lowercase letter or a word boundary that is not preceded by optional uppercase letters.

Comment: Did you have time to check my approach?

Comment: I did, but RegEx is hard enough without having to decipher the \p{Lu} syntax. I've tested it and it didn't work correctly for "ABC Test" as it output "AB C Test" when I am expected "ABC Test"

Comment: It is not so, have a closer look at the Context tab on RegexStorm demo.  It shows `​ABC Test`. `\p{Lu}` is an uppercase letter, `\p{Ll}` is a lowercase one, and *this supports Unicode*. It will work with Russian or Polish, and other scripts that have upper/lower case.

Comment: I tested it in LinqPad using the following code and it came back with "AB C Test":     string value = "ABC Test";
string matches = Regex.Replace(value, @"(?<!^|\b|\p{Lu})\p{Lu}+(?=\p{Ll}|\b)|(?<!^|\b)\p{Lu}(?=\p{Ll}|\b)", " $0", RegexOptions.Compiled);

matches.Dump();

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a requirement to use Regex? To be honest, I wouldn't use Regex for this at all. They're hard to debug and not especially readable.

- You also sometimes end up with all sorts of fun like this: [Regex problem: IsMatch method never returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525919/regex-problem-ismatch-method-never-returns)
- The regex above will not deal with the wonderful world of unicode - e.g. Cyrillics (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script) (not that your specific problem domain probably needs this, but for completeness...)

I would go with a small, reusable, easily testable extension method:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] inputs = new[]
        {
            "ABCTest",
            "HelloWorld",
            "testTest$Test",
            "aaҚbb"
        };

        var output = inputs.Select(x => x.SplitWithSpaces(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture));

        foreach (string x in output)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool IsLowerCase(this TextInfo textInfo, char input)
    {
        return textInfo.ToLower(input) == input;
    }

    public static string SplitWithSpaces(this string input, CultureInfo culture = null)
    {
        if (culture == null)
        {
            culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        }
        TextInfo textInfo = culture.TextInfo;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);

        for (int i = 1; i < sb.Length; i++)
        {
            int previous = i - 1;

            if (textInfo.IsLowerCase(sb[previous]))
            {
                int insertLocation = previous - 1;

                if (insertLocation > 0)
                {
                    sb.Insert(insertLocation, ' ');
                }

                while (i < sb.Length && textInfo.IsLowerCase(sb[i]))
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }                
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't need to handle culture variances and feel OhAuth's answer is more straight forward and more concise, even if it has a regular expression which aren't the easiest to understand at the best of times!