# regex for windows path

Tags: java, regex

As part of fortify fix we need to validate a filepath. For example,

1. `"C:/Users/<username>/sample1.txt"`
2. `"C:\Users\<username>\sample1.txt"`

We have tried with the below regex for validating the above paths but we ended up with error when a filepath contains `\`.
So please suggest the valid regex which can accept both the slashes in a filepath.

```
Validator.FilePath=.*[\\]\\[!"#$%&'()_*+,/:;<=>?@\\^`{|}~].*
```

Comment: Do you just want to check whether the path is valid or whether it actually exists? In the latter case I'd just create a new `File` object and let the framework handle path conversion. In the former case you could do something similar but iterate through the parent hierarchy and check each parent until you hit a certain condition. - Alternatively you could have a look at libraries like Apache Commons IO which normally have path related utilities.

Comment: have you tried like :-    .*(\/|\\).*(\\|\/)[!"#$%&'()_*+,\/:;<=>?@\\^`{|}~].*

Comment: private ESAPIValidationUtils() { }

  public static String getValidFilePath(String reqParam) {
   String validFileName = "";
   try {
    if (null != reqParam) {
     validFileName = ESAPI.validator().getValidInput("File Path: ", reqParam, "FilePath", 256, true);
    }
   } catch (ValidationException ex) {
    Log.error("com.dextersystems.util.ESAPIValidationUtils", "getValidFilePath()", ex);
   }
   return validFileName;
  }

Answer (score 7):

You can try:

```
[a-zA-Z]:[\\\/](?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\\\/])*([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.txt)
```

- `[a-zA-Z]:` is for the drive letter and `:`.
- `[\\\/]` to match either `\` or `/`.
- `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\\\/])*` is for folder names. You can add any charcters in the character class that you may need. I used only `a-zA-Z0-9`.
- `([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.txt)` is for the file name and `.txt` extension - it matches the file name, with the extension, and captures it.

Comment: How to match space in folder name and file name as well

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]:[\\\\/](?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\\\\/])*([a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.(xls|xlsx))",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("e:/avinash/testing file.xlsx");
               Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("e:/avinash testing/testing file.xlsx");
  boolean matchFound = matcher.find(); 
This is not working. Any help

Comment: Is the backslash needed before the forward slash in [\\\/]. I would think [\\/] would work too.

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, this is the pattern I've used for ages to validate any valid Windows path + file:

```
^
  (?<drive>[a-z]:)?
  (?<path>(?:[\\]?(?:[\w !#()-]+|[.]{1,2})+)*[\\])?
  (?<filename>(?:[.]?[\w !#()-]+)+)?[.]?
$
```

It accommodates the drive letter being present or absent, an optional root marker, relative paths ("." and ".."), and periods in file and folder names. It also makes extracting that information simple/easy via capture-group labels. The lone caveat is that it necessitates a secondary check for double-periods in the path names which it passes..

[Regex 101 example](https://regex101.com/r/9J5JPW/1)

Comment: Looks nice but it does not cover the opposite slashes.

Comment: @Dariusz -- Uh, that's because, as the opening line states, It was originally written _strictly_ for validating _Windows_ paths and I just don't care that Windows has recently added automatic unix-grammar interpolation. Still, if you feel that you absolutely need to add support for _Unix_ paths, it's a pretty easy/obvious/straightforward modification...

Comment: does not satify a lot of variations: eg. "+" is allowed in a filename, as are some other characters. and multiple consecutive dots are allowed. etc.

Comment: The 'plus' sign was a special character (used for file concatenation) in DOS 8.3 filenames, and it is also one amongst an assortment of ill-advised characters to allow within filenames according to best-practices. Likewise, accommodating consecutive periods is an INVITATION for path misuse, is also contrary to best-practices, and I'm beyond wholly uninterested in allowing either one. Nevertheless, if you're ambivalent to best practices, and want to accept more characters than I, the pattern is pretty easy to modify...

Comment: This regex won't work with this filepath:
"C:\abc\folderone\foldertwo\test\my.subfolder\another_subfolder\Filename.AlphaBetaGamma.txt"

Found a hint to that issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525919/regex-problem-ismatch-method-never-returns

Always ends in an infinite loop. (.NET RegEx Class)

Comment: @MarcusD -- Okay, though I'm unsure as to how an apparent deficiency/error within the .NET class code itself is somehow my responsibility, nor how that issue somehow invalidates the applicability of this pattern... ‍♀️

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
^(?i)\s*([a-z]:/?)?(?:[^?*:;|<>\r\n\\]*)(/\1*|\1*)(.\1*)*[^.]$
```

satisfies:

```
c:
c:/
c:notepad++
c:/notepad++
notepad
C:/not epad++/notepad++/notepad++.exe.txt.xaml
C:notepad++/notepad++/notepad++.exe.txt.xaml
C:notepad++//notepad++/notepad++...exe.txt.xaml
C:notepad++/notepad++
.xaml
 c:notepad++/
 C:/notepad++/notepad++/
 C:/notepad++/notepad++/a
 C:/notep ad++/notepad++
```

But not:

```
C:notepad++/notepad++/notepad++.exe.txt.
```

Comment: Why the self-referencing groups? This expression will also match f.ex `someone@example.com`, ``/\/\/\`` and a newline character.

Comment: As written this is missing two escapes ( Regex101: [link](https://regex101.com/r/D01d3B/1) ); with those fixed, it doesn't provide capture groups for the drive, path or filename, and it creates empty/null capture groups in literally every example you gave. It also accepts colons and slashes anywhere throughout the pattern, including passing the strings `:::::::::::::::::::` and `\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\` as a valid paths + filenames. Whitespace at the beginning or end should not be accepted, but this allows both. In fact, I could not actually _find_ a string that this pattern would actually reject.

Comment: I stand corrected: literally _any_ string that ends in a period will fail, even though having a trailing period is acceptable in windows filenames... This pattern also apparently validates asterisks and question marks (i.e. wildcard chars), greater-than, less-than, and pipe characters (i.e. redirects) as well as double/single/back quotes in the middle of filenames. It apparently thinks `>::"woops!"*?<|` is a valid Windows filename, for example.

Comment: strange thing is, that making a file in explorer with the name >::"woops!"*?<| works very well. Only, it is automatically changed by explorer into woops!. So: is it valid or not?

Comment: Indeed I was way to quick with my regexpr..
I learned a few things though:
1: regexpr is a snake pit
2: first question to answer : do I need regexpr at all? In my case: I realized I do not need to check the validity of a file name, but whether my program can find the file (File.Exists(.....)).
3: It is not always necessary to find a universal regexr for filenames. Many use cases require a special one.
4: it's not always clear what "valid filename"  means.

Answer (score -1):

```
Validator.FilePath=(?:[a-zA-Z]\\:|[\\\\\\\\|/]+[\\w\\.]+)[\\\\|/]?([\\w]+[\\\\|/])*[\\w]*(\\.\\w+)$
```

Comment: Try to explain your solution a bit.

Comment: Does not satisfy any of my tests as seen above.