# Search paths on document and save them in array

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I want to search for Windows paths on complete HTML document and save them in a array. The paths can be completely different. Except for the drive letter, everything that comes after it is uncertain.

For example my HTML:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
<br>
<br>
C:\Users\max\Documents<br>
S:\Data\Customer<br>
<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
```

Comment: Where do you do the search? Is that you need to acquire such paths in the HTML file and store them to an array? Could you please clarify in which programming language is this occasion?

Comment: @DhanaD. Unfortunately, I lack the approach to do so. So far I've tried to work with the ".match" function and looked at regex.

The whole thing would like to implement with Vanillia JS.

Comment: So, you want to write the JS code in that HTML file to inquire those paths in that HTML file??

Comment: Exactly. So I just have the above paths as an array.

Comment: Since those paths inside the `p` tag, you can search the innerHTML and use regex to extract the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following regex to find matches in your `document.body` :

`/[a-zA-Z]:[\\\/](?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\\\/])*[a-zA-Z0-9]+/gm`

```js
let matches = [...document.body.innerHTML.matchAll(/[a-zA-Z]:[\\\/](?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\\\/])*[a-zA-Z0-9]+/gm)];
console.log(matches);
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
<br>
<br>
C:\Users\max\Documents<br>
S:\Data\Customer<br>
<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```js
const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML
const foundPaths = body.match(/^([a-zA-Z]:[\\\/](?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\\\/])*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/gm)
console.log(foundPaths)

// Expected output:
//   [object Array] (2) ["C:\Users\max\Documents","S:\Data\Customer"]
```

This is Javascript snippet you could paste in the page in a `<script>` tag.

Sources:
[regex for windows path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747139/regex-for-windows-path)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions
Usefull:
https://regex101.com/